# cannot find DiscoveryClient bean error in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

```
2017-03-16 16:09:08.821  INFO 9104 --- [           main] com.hello.EurekaClientApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-16 16:09:08.848  INFO 9104 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5dcd8c7a: startup date [Thu Mar 16 16:09:08 CDT 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@441772e
2017-03-16 16:09:09.873  INFO 9104 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'hystrixFeature' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hystrixFeature; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration$HystrixWebConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration; factoryMethodName=hystrixFeature; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.class]]
2017-03-16 16:09:10.364  WARN 9104 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2017-03-16 16:09:10.701  INFO 9104 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=d0eb8cfd-bd5b-3565-9f63-f671e896f6be
2017-03-16 16:09:10.736  INFO 9104 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-16 16:09:11.312  INFO 9104 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94394ff6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-16 16:09:12.091  INFO 9104 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-16 16:09:12.128  INFO 9104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-16 16:09:12.130  INFO 9104 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-03-16 16:09:12.546  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-16 16:09:12.547  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3699 ms
2017-03-16 16:09:13.191  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'proxyStreamServlet' to [/proxy.stream]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.193  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.198  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.199  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.199  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.200  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.200  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.200  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.200  INFO 9104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-16 16:09:13.269  WARN 9104 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaClientApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientservice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientService' defined in file [C:\Users\Mike\workspace\Eureka_client\target\classes\com\hello\ClientService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2017-03-16 16:09:13.306  INFO 9104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-03-16 16:09:13.404  INFO 9104 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-16 16:09:13.745 ERROR 9104 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.hello.ClientService required a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient' in your configuration.
```

```
package com.hello;

import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Service
public class ClientService {

private final DiscoveryClient disc;

    public ClientService(DiscoveryClient disc){
        this.disc=disc;
    }



    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="disp")
    public String serviceInstancesByApplicationName(){
        return this.disc.getInstancesById("a-bootiful-client").toString();
    }

    public String disp(){
        return "This is fall back method";
    }
}




package com.hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.EnableHystrix;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.EnableHystrixDashboard;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;


@EnableHystrix
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class EurekaClientApplication {


    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientservice;




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/serv")
    public String serviceInstancesByApplicationName(){
        return clientservice.serviceInstancesByApplicationName();
    }
}
```

i am trying to create a simple eureka service and client program and enable hystrix on that. but i am getting this error on the code

Comment: SO is not a debugging service.  Please add text explaining what you've tried to do to investigate your problem.  Explain which part of your code seems to work the way you want and which part doesn't.  Demonstrate some effort on your side, otherwise it looks like you just dump a big error message and expect people to debug your code for you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You imported wrong `DiscoveryClient` class in your code. DiscoveryClient from netflix is not provided as Spring Bean. So you should use one from spring-cloud.

Try to import `org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient` instead of `com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient` in your `ClientService` class.

Also you need to change `this.disc.getInstancesById("a-bootiful-client")` to `this.disc.getInstances(...)`.

Answer (score 9):

This would be because of 2 cases.

1: The first situation is whether the imported package does not match

If you used **@EnableDiscoveryClient**

`import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient`
"instead of "
`com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient`

If you used **@EnableEurekaClient** use this below import

`import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient`

2: I did not select the `starer-web` dependency when I created the module, have added this below dependency in ***pom.xml*** and *`rebuild`* the project to fetch the added dependency.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient` instead of `com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient`. This is the discovery client provided by Netflix.

If you want to use spring discovery client then use `org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient` as suggested by @yongsung.yoon

Answer (score 3):

I've also faced with the same issue, I solved it after adding spring boot-starter-web dependency

Answer (score 0):

You can check for 2 things in the project.

1. Check if you have added the **spring-web** dependency in your pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Check if you have added the below 2 Annotations on the Main Spring Boot Application Class :

```html
1. @EnableEurekaClient
   from import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

2. @EnableDiscoveryClient
   from import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
```